# ViewPager, но без перелистывания на другую страницу

Tags: android-viewpager, android

Как организовать слайдинг, но без анимации перехода на другую страницу. Мне надо задействовать смысл  реализации ViewPager, только не могу найти примеров.

Comment: Что имеете в виду под "слайдинг, но без анимации перехода на другую страницу"?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно установить свой *[ViewPager.PageTransformer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html)*, который бы показывал смену view, как будто анимации нет:

```
    mViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
            int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
            if (position <= -1) { // [-Infinity,-1]
                view.setTranslationX(0);
            } else if (position < -0.5) { // (-1,-0.5)
                view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * (-1-position));
            } else if (position < 0.5) { // [-0.5,0.5)
                view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);
            } else if (position < 1) { // (0.5,1)
                view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * (1 - position));
            } else { // [1,+Infinity]
                view.setTranslationX(0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Но возможно, вы просто хотите выполнять какие-то действия по свайпу, либо другим жестам. Т.е. установить *[GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html)* и слушать события *onFling*, либо *onScroll*

В доокументации есть хорошая [глава про жесты.](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html)